# Do I need to use an underscore separator in the aggregation query?

Tags: getstream-io

Is it ok to use a **(semicolon) ;** separator instead of **(underscore) _**
and adding my own format for easier parsing in the aggregation?

It looks like at the end it just needs to be a string so probably doesn't
matter but would like confirmation. 
This is an example aggregation I would like to do.

```
object_type={{object_type}};verb={{verb.infinitive}};target={{target }};actor={{actor}};time={{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")}}
```

The example shows something like this:

```
{{ actor }}_{{ verb.id }}_{{ time.strftime('%H') }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's just a string. This shouldn't be a problem. Also we're going to be releasing a new interface which will make it easier to test different aggregation formats.